# Create smaller title size in matlab

Tags: matlab, title

I have 4 different subplots and I would like to create main title, I read that this can be done by using `suptitle` function, however, it worked well but the problem is that the title is too bold and large. How can I make it smaller ?!

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 4):

Save the handle to the text label generated with `suptitle`, and set the [text properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html):

```
h = suptitle(...)
set(h,'FontSize',20,'FontWeight','normal')
```